# Binding textbox from one WPF window to another

Tags: wpf, data-binding, visual-studio-2013

I am unsure on how to bind the text in a textbox from one WPF window to another textbox in another window.

The premise is basically when I click the button on one WPF window after entering data in the textbox in that window, it should be visible in the WPF window which is being opened.
I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Maybe you should be using the `MVVM` pattern, have a `ViewModel` behind you new `Window`, and sync your `ViewModels` via some kind of `EventAggregator`.

Comment: If you're creating new window in the code-behind then just use the text value from your `TextBox`. If however you need it bound so when updated in the first Window you want the update to be reflected in the other one you could set the `DataContext` to the same `ViewModel`. And then Bind the new Window to the same `Property` as your first `Window`. HTH